# What does "Constant wind condition during flight" mean?

Tags: weather, flight-planning, terminology

What is constant wind condition during flight? Is it zero wind velocity at an instant (say at level flight) or wind with constant speed, say 20 m/sec (at steady level flight or whatever it is) Which statement is correct?

Answer (score 4):

It means constant, or unchanging wind magnitude and direction.  It could be still air or just a constant upper level wind.  That can happen on local flights but is rare on long cross country flights.